# How to update ad description using pre_item_add hook in OsClass?

Tags: osclass

I am writing a function to change the external links to my redirection link. I use pre_item_add hook, but I don't know how to update the submitted description with the new one. Does anyone know how to do it?

This is my idea:

```
function link_process($aItem){
    $desc = $_POST['description'][$language_code];
    Session::newInstance()->_setForm('description' , rewriteExternal($desc));
}
osc_add_hook('pre_item_add', 'link_process');
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar change described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015613/how-to-modify-ft-min-word-len-4-to-ft-min-word-len-1-so-that-osclass-3-7-1-can-s)

Look for point 8. In my solution, but read all the answers to understand. Also there is a link in the solution to where I got this idea.