# Search shows nothing if user types category name in search bar in osclass

Tags: search, osclass

I hope this will help others too.
The search bar shows nothing if a user types category/sub-category name in the search bar.
I know there is a separate field for selecting category/sub-category along with the search bar but in my case i have only a single search bar and when i search by typing the category/sub-category name the search shows me 0 results found even though i have items in the category/sub-category. 
Is there anyone could assist me the solution please

Answer (score 0):

The search in osclass is made by title and description only. If you insert the category name into the description then it will work as you want.

In your theme's functions.php file, add to the end

```
<?php
function endsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
$length = strlen($needle);

return $length === 0 || 
(substr($haystack, -$length) === $needle);
}
function mc_addcategory($desc, $catId) {
$Cat = Category::newInstance()->toRootTree($catId);
$d = '\n\n  ';
foreach($Cat as $c) {
$d = $d . $c["s_name"] .' / ';
}
if(endsWith($desc, $d))
return $desc;
else return $desc . $d;
}
function mc_filter_description($aItem) {

    foreach(@$aItem['description'] as $key => $value) {
        $aItem['description'][$key] = mc_addcategory($value,$aItem['catId']);
    }

    return $aItem;
}

osc_add_filter('item_add_prepare_data', 'mc_filter_description');
osc_add_filter('item_edit_prepare_data', 'mc_filter_description');
?>
```

Step 2

You would want to remove the added text from description when displaying the description to the public and to the owner when it edits hi's item.
You can do that  with a function
Put this before the above code in functions.php

```
<?php
    function mc_hide_categ_in_description($desc, $catId) {

    $Cat = Category::newInstance()->toRootTree($catId);
    $d = '\n\n  ';
    foreach($Cat as $c) {
    $d = $d . $c["s_name"] .' / ';
    }
    if(endsWith($desc, $d))
    return str_replace($d,'',$desc);
    else return $desc;
    }
?>
```

and call this function where the description is shown. Have a look here

[How to modify ft_min_word_len=4 to ft_min_word_len=1 so that osclass 3.7.1 can search min 1 character word, instead of 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015613/how-to-modify-ft-min-word-len-4-to-ft-min-word-len-1-so-that-osclass-3-7-1-can-s)

And see where I call 'removeunderline(' for description.

OBS

After this you must update the descriptions in your db by editing and saving each item.
This will work if the item is edited and it's category is changed by user.

If the admin makes the editing and the above function can't be called from oc-admin/themes/modern... files, the last function from above must be placed in /oc-includes/osclass/helpers/hSearch.php and removed from functions.php file.